# Push data into json file using AngularJs and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular JS, and am trying to make a CRUD form using AngularJs and Json with javascript without using any other server side language. The script is working fine but is unable to write data to the JSON file on same server in same directory. I am using xamp. Here is the code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">     </script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app="myapp">
     <div ng-controller="MyController" >
     <form>
       <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="myForm.name" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="12"> Name <br/>
       <select ng-model="myForm.car">
         <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
         <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
         <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
       </select>

       <button ng-click="myForm.submitTheForm()">Submit Form</button>
     </form>

     <div>
      {{myForm.name}}
     </div>
     <div>
      {{myForm.car}}
     </div>
   </div>

   <script>
     angular.module("myapp", [])
     .controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.myForm = {};
       $scope.myForm.name = "Jakob Jenkov";
       $scope.myForm.car  = "nissan";
     console.log("Submitting form");
     $scope.myForm.submitTheForm = function(item, event) {
       console.log("Submitting form");
       var dataObject = {
          Name : $scope.myForm.name
          ,City  : $scope.myForm.car
          ,Country  : "India"
       };

       var responsePromise = $http.post("data.json", dataObject);
       responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(dataFromServer.title);
       });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("Submitting form failed!");
       });
     }

      $http.get('data.json').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you can't perform CRUD operations without a server side language like node or php....

Comment: Finally found a answer. Will be using PHP as the server side language for this one. Although we can use other server side languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

You doing it wrong. There should be some API on your backend for this. You can use expressjs - it is pretty simple:

```
app.post('cars/', function(req, res) {
  writeToFile('data.json', req.body); // I do not know how to write files, something like this
  res.send();
})
```

Comment: what is `writeToFile('data.json', req.body);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can post anything to the json file, since its just a file and not anything (API URL) on server.